# Distinct count of users in the last 7 days for the last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct-values

I want to count the number of unique users in the last 7 days for the last 7 days. I want to build a table that has a column of dates (the current day to 7 days into the past) and the corresponding value is the number of unique users 7 days into the past. I have a calendar table to use that has daily dates.

Example of available data:

```
insert_date  |  user
1-1-22       |  A
1-1-22       |  B
1-1-22       |  C
1-3-22       |  D
1-3-22       |  A
1-5-22       |  B
1-9-22       |  C
1-11-22      |  D
1-11-22      |  F
```

Desired output:

```
date         | distinct users
1-5-22       | 4
1-6-22       | 4
1-7-22       | 4
1-8-22       | 3
1-9-22       | 4
1-10-22      | 2      (e.g. 1-4-22 to 1-10-22 -> B, C)
1-11-22      | 4      (e.g. 1-5-22 to 1-11-22 -> B, C, D, F)
```

Comment: In sql server, select count(DISTINCT user),insert_date from   table
group by insert_date

Comment: 1) MySQL and SQL Server are very different. Which dbms are you using? 2) What is the data type of `insert_date`. The samples make it look like a varchar? 3) Does `insert_date` contain only a date value "2002-01-03" or both date and time ("2022-01-03 14:28:33") 4) What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags

Comment: As per the question guide please show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a Calendar Table, something like the following should suffice:

With a Calendar table and column named `CalendarDate`, use an `apply` to count users per date:

```
select d.calendardate, u.qty
from CalendarTable d
outer apply (
    select Count(distinct user_name)
    from create_user u
    where u.insert_date = d.CalendarDate
)u(qty)
where d.CalendarDate >= DateAdd(day,-7,GetDate()) and d.CalendarDate <= GetDate();
```